# Converting an integer to Char Pointer using C

Tags: c++

I am trying to convert an integer to a char pointer as shown below. The data results are different. I am not sure what is going wrong. Please help me in correcting the code.

```
int main(){ 
    char *key1 = "/introduction";
    std::ostringstream str1;
    str1<< 10;   
    std::string data=str1.str();
    std::cout <<"The data value="<<data<<std::endl;  // The data value= 10
    char *intro= new char[data.length()+1];
    
    strcpy(intro, data.c_str());
    std::cout <<"The data value="<<*intro <<std::endl; // The data value=1
          
    return 0;
}
```

I am not sure why two data value are printed different i.e, 10 and 1.

Comment: This is C++, not C. Remove the `c` tag.

Comment: `*intro` should be `intro`

Comment: It worked. Thank you @IłyaBursov for the great help. Please explain me the reason if possible.

Comment: There are loads of unnecessary conversions there but oh well...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++, when trying to print all the contents of a `char *` with `cout`, you should pass the pointer, i.e. `cout << intro << endl`.

What you've done here is dereferenced the `char *`, so `cout << *intro << endl` is equivalent to `cout << intro[0] << endl`, which is equivalent to printing the first character, `1`.